# Query Pulling Users Back Which Don't Meet Criteria of WHERE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-clause

I'm retrieving users from the database to display in a dropdown list.  I need all the users that match the correct group id and that are also in a one of two particular roles.  Here is the statement I have so far:

```
SELECT a.USER_ID AS userid, a.GROUP_ID, a.ROLE, 
b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME FROM b_sonet_user2group a 
INNER JOIN b_user b ON a.USER_ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.GROUP_ID = $groupid 
AND a.ROLE = 'A' OR a.ROLE = 'E'
```

This is pulling in users that aren't even in the group though and I have outputted $groupid and it is showing the correct number.  Am I doing something wrong with the WHERE section of this query? I'm also getting a repeat of one user when they only appear once in the user list which meets that criteria.  If I'm missing something simple here let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can you try this:**

```
SELECT a.USER_ID AS userid, a.GROUP_ID, a.ROLE, 
b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME FROM b_sonet_user2group a 
INNER JOIN b_user b ON a.USER_ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.GROUP_ID = $groupid 
AND (a.ROLE = 'A' OR a.ROLE = 'E')
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: This worked perfectly! I knew it was around this area of the statement.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Andy.Welcome :) , Can you please mark it as answer so that it will be useful for others..

Comment: Will do when it lets me, just have to wait 5 minutes ;) Thanks again.

Comment: @andy..no problem..okay

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [**IN Clause**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) instead on **OR**.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.USER_ID AS userid, a.GROUP_ID, a.ROLE, b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME 
FROM b_sonet_user2group a 
INNER JOIN b_user b ON a.USER_ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.GROUP_ID = $groupid AND a.ROLE IN ('A', 'E');
```

Comment: @andy As per me you have to use IN clause instead of OR if you concern about performance.